# Повтор трека в аудиоплеере wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, аудио, mp3

Пишу сейчас свой аудиоплеер и хочу добавить фичу бесконечного воспроизведения одного трека. Но никак не получается это сделать. Пользуюсь библиотекой WMPLib. Хочу сделать так чтобы на нажатие на кнопку повторялся 1 и тот же трек, пока значение bool равен true(но необязательно именно так). Перекопал ру инет сегмент и анг сегмент, видел примеры решения проблем но ни один из них не смог решить проблему.
Примерно так хотел реализовать, но как вы поняли уже и это не помогло.

```
if(flag==true)
{
     if(текущее время трека==время конца трека)
          сбросить время трека на 0;
}
```

Можно как то решить эту проблему?

Comment: Вам надо использовать подписку на событие `Player.PlayStateChange` и в методе проверять что плейер состояние сменилось на `WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsStopped` и тогда запускать снова воспроизведение. [см док.](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/wmp/creating-the-windows-media-player-control-programmatically?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: в WPF нет события PlayStateChange, уже пробовал этот решение

Comment: А причем здесь WPF? Вы по ссылке ходили? Там же есть примеры кода.

Comment: Еще раз говорю, пробовал я этот способ

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос сам.
Решил далеко не идеально, с помощью выдумывания костылей, матов, и терпения.
При нажатии на кнопку ставил flag=!flag и передавал значение в конструктор класса который отслеживал статус воспроизведения
и

```
 if (flag == true&&PlayingStatus==Status.Playing)
      Repeat();
```

В методе Repeat выполнял код почти как выше, только без проверки на значение bool и с преобразованием TimeSpanов в числовое значение int с количеством секунд в треке(иначе из-за значения после запятой проверка не выполнялась со значением true)